# IIS Express SSL Request Redirection Issue

Tags: iis, express, iis-express

I have a port conflict issue. I need my IISExpress to be able to cater these web request:

**http:// localhost:44567/**

and

**https:// localhost:44567/**

I know these are conflicting ports since SSL connection should have its own port.
I am also aware that we can solve this from the client side by changing requesting link to a different port.

But what I am looking is, if there is a way from the server side(IISExpress) to resolve this problem. Like for example:

If IISExpress receives http:// localhost:44567/ then it will serve it as it is. And if it receives a request for(SSL) https:// localhost:44567/ it will redirect it to a different port, let us say to https:// localhost:44569/. Or maybe changing https:// to http://?

Is there a way to do this in IISExpress?

Or is there another approach to this problem?

**NOTE:** I need a solution for the server side and not from the client side. Thank you.
**NOTE:** I intentionally put space in the domain name because I am not allowed to put links in the question.